# С помощью чего сохранить в память телефона установленное изображение в ImageView? С помощью какого метода?

Tags: android, imageview

Я знаю только метод Shared Preferences для сохранения. Но, кажется, он не сохраняет изображения. Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: А в ImageView он откуда взялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще sharedPreferences используется для хранения простых данных. Например вы можете сохранить имя и id пользователя. Для сохранения изображения нужно писать картинку в память устройства. Например можно сделать так:

```
private fun saveImage(image: Bitmap, fileName: String): Uri? {
        val imagesFolder = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
        var uri: Uri? = null
        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs()
            val file = File(imagesFolder, fileName)
            val stream = FileOutputStream(file)
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)
            stream.flush()
            stream.close()
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "package_name", file)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.i("IOException while trying to write file for sharing:  ${e.message}")
        }
        return uri
    }
```

таким способом вы сможете сохранить данные в папку cashe вашего приложения. Вот есть подобный вопрос: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480906/save-bitmap-to-app-folder). Вот [туториал](https://medium.com/@maksymilian.wojcik/android-saving-files-in-internal-storage-image-from-byte-array-etc-dd7d1b86d309) так же есть для решения данного вопроса.

### UPDATE

Вот вариант на java:

```
private void saveReceivedImage(Bitmap image, String imageName){
    try {
        File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "MyAppName" + File.separator + "Images");
        if(!path.exists()){
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        File outFile = new File(path, imageName + ".jpeg");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Saving received message failed with", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Saving received message failed with", e);
    }
}
```

для того чтобы использовать данный метод нужно его вызывать так:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
saveReceivedImage(bitmap, "some_name");
```

Comment: Почему вы написали другим языком? Напишите пожалуйста на Java  который используется в Андроид Студио. Вот почему я вопрос перезадал. Хотя согласен можно было и у вас спросить

Comment: в проекте на android можно использовать не только java если что)) это например котлин который похож на java, сейчас отредактирую ответ

Comment: Знаю)) но я пока начинающий. Спасибо тебе. И Извини если мой маленький мозгик не сможет понять то что ты мне объесняешь :(

Comment: @onegingek, отредактировал ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: уберите context, вы работаете из активности, он там не нужен

Comment: это отдельный метод должен быть, не нужно его пихать внутрь `onCreate()` он должен быть за его пределами

Comment: Блин. Смог. Спасибо тебе Большое! Скажи пожалуйста, как ты учился андроид разработке? Ну то есть где ты брал информацию? И сколько времени у тебя заняло чтобы хотя бы более менее узнать разраб под андроид

Comment: учился как и все в гугле) время зависит от человека и от желания :) Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108417/discussion-between-andrew-and-onegingek).